# jquery autocomplete in codeigniter dont work propertly

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

When I search it give to me not good results when I write lastname or firstname what is in db it not find it. And empty msg dont work too. Thanks
This is my controller:

```
class Search extends CI_Controller{
  function index(){
    $this->load->view('search_view');
  }

  function search_users(){
    $this->load->model('search_model');
    if (isset($_GET['term'])){
      $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
      $this->search_model->search($q);
    }
  }
}
```

This is model:

```
class Search_model extends CI_Model{
      function search($q){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->like('CONCAT(user_profiles.firstn, " ", user_profiles.lastn)', $q);
        $query = $this->db->get('user_profiles');
        $query = $this->db->get('user_profiles');
    $row_set = array();
    $temp = array();

    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
            $temp['id'] = $row['id'];
            $temp['label'] = $row['firstn'].' '.$row['lastn'];
            $row_set[] = $temp; 
        }
          echo json_encode($row_set);
        }
      }
    }
```

and this is my view:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#empty-message { float: left; }
input { float: left }
</style>



<input type="text" id="search" />

<script>

$(function(){
    $('#search').autocomplete({
        source: "search/search_users",
        minLength:0,

        response: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                $("#empty-message").text("No results found");
            }
            else {
                $("#empty-message").empty();
            }
        }

    });


});
</script>
```

if i use $this->db->last_query() and i put 'a' in label it give to me this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`user_profiles`)
WHERE  CONCAT(user_profiles.meno, " ", user_profiles.priezvisko)  LIKE '%a%'
```

and this is result:

```
[{"id":"5","label":"Janosik icloud"},{"id":"7","label":"Janosik iicloud"},{"id":"8","label":"Janosik Smrdi"}]
```

but if i put other letter it write blank page no last query no result
this is my table
id  -- user_id  -- role -- firstn  -- lastn  -- birthd  -- city avatar  -- profil_pic
1 --
1 --
admin --
Aykon --
Aykonov --
1990-06-09 --
Zilina --
NULL --
NULL --

5 --
6 --
user --
Janosik --
icloud --
1999-05-06 --
Zilina --
NULL --
NULL --

6 --
7 --
user --
Aykon --
Outlook --
1800-06-08 --
NULL --
NULL --
NULL --

7 --
8 --
user --
Janosik --
iicloud --
1000-08-09 --
NULL --
NULL --
NULL --

8 --
9 --
user --
Janosik --
Smrdi --
0000-00-00 --
NULL --
NULL --
NULL --

Comment: Did you try LOWER(CONCAT(NANES)) and strtolower($string)?

Comment: I try it thanks but it work Only query with one letter when i put second it return blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this will help you
in controller

```
function search($q)
{
    $this->db->select('firstn,lastn');
    $this->db->like('CONCAT(user_profiles.firstn, " ", user_profiles.lastn)', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('user_profiles');
    $row_set = array();
    $temp = array();
    if($query->num_rows > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            // give your id
            $temp['id'] = $row['id']; 
            // give your label
            $temp['label'] = $row['label']; 
            $row_set[] = $temp;
        }
    }
     echo json_encode($row_set);
     die;
}
```

in a view

```
<script>

$(function(){
    $('#search').autocomplete({
        source: "search/search_users",
        minLength:0,
        response: function(event, ui) {
            var c = ui.content.length;
            check_data(c);
        }

    });
});

function check_data(data)
{
    if(data === 0)
    {
          $("#empty-message").text('No results found');
    }
    else
    {
        $("#empty-message").text( '' );
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks to reply but it still search only few names from db for example I have about 7 names and it find still the same names (about 3) in other situation it find nothing and dont show msg

Comment: Please you can provide me your test example and name which you have in your DB ?  you can debug your query using $this->db->last_query(); and check is your query is correct ?

Comment: run your debug query on your MySQL server compare both results.

Answer (score 0):

- Print the variable `$q` at the beginning of your controller method
- Print the variable `$q` before the model method
- Print the query run to check if your `$q` is correctly send to your model.

[Doc Codeigniter - last_query()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html)

Comment: q is send correctly when I put only one letter when I put second nothing happen